# Should I switch to UDP for a mobile p2p game when considering 3G network?

Tags: networking, client-server, mobile, udp, peer-to-peer

I have been making a mobile game that is similar to "Street Fighter" where two players play with each other via Internet.

The game sends out a small packet (controller status) to the other party every 30ms (a lot of packets going on).

I am currently using a server to connect two players and all communications are via TCP through the server. The server load increases a lot even for just 30 concurrent players. I know it sounds not wise to let the communication go through the server, so I think the best design should let these two players to communicate directly via UDP after the server hooks them up.

However, I have some questions when trying to move on to the new design:

Since it's a mobile game, players might be using 3G network a lot. Does UDP hole punching work well in 3G network? Does it matter when a player is actually moving physically (such as inside a car)? Do you think I should change the design or any recommendation of better design concepts?

Answer (score 4):

3G is optimized for stuff like streaming video. It's terrible with regard to latency when talking about small bits of data. There's a reason multiplayer mobile games over 3G with split-second timing don't exist.

Comment: Yes, some said it can't but I also found some said it's doable: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/network-over-3g.69367/

Comment: I don't see anything there that leads me to believe a "a mobile game that is similar to 'Street Fighter'" would work. I see people talking about how in an FPS you can get killed by a late packet and not really know if it missed you on your client or not because you can't see yourself.

Comment: I did make some experiments with 3G and the latency is pretty bad. I thought if I change the app to send UDP directly to each other, the situation can be improved. Ok, maybe I shall consider to give up the idea then.

Comment: It's unpleasant to have to say "give up on the idea" but in this case, I don't think the technology will deliver what you need. :(